# Is there a typo in this exercise, or am I not counting correctly?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, time-signatures, classical-guitar

I have this set of right hand open string exercises for classical guitar.  Many are in 4/4 but some are in 6/8 (see pic below).  The notes are grouped in 6 but there is no tuple notation.  Reading as straight 6/8 I expect 12 16th notes per measure.  Lines 1 and 2 show 24 16th notes per measure.  My question is am I reading it wrong or is there a missing bar in each line separating each into 2 groups of 12 16th notes.  Thanks.

[image: This is a pic of some right hand exercises from La Technica Degli Arpeggi]

Comment: Is this the only seeming mistake in the book?

Comment: It's rampant throughout all 6exercises in 6/8 time.  But a consistent mistake.

Comment: Does the sheet have an annotation that all notes should be played half the written value?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't.

Comment: Yep, it's missing bar lines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's incorrect. Either it's in 12/8, or there's a barline missing, or they should be demi-semiquavers.

Comment: If they are 32nd notes, then the lower voice should execute dotted eighth notes.

Answer (score 8):

It's definitely a typo. You can tell by the lowest voice which always has a dotted quarter note per group of 16th notes. As currently written, it is in 12/8 . It could be in 6/8 if the bar line was instead after every two groups.